# Why would a special ansible variable be undefined?

Tags: ansible, yaml, continuous-deployment

I have been working recently on an anible script for CD and have began to run into an issue. When I run the most recent YAML file I get an error

```
fatal: [Windows-AWS]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible_play_name' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in 'x.yml': line 32, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Add RabbitMQ user\n ^ here\n"}
```

The variable in question in contained in the code like this:

```
- name: Add RabbitMQ user
  win_shell: |
    Set-Location "C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-{{rabbitmq_version}}\sbin"
    $users = .\rabbitmqctl.bat list_users

    if($users -Like "*{{ansible_play_name}}*")
    {
      Write-Host "Skipping: '{{ansible_play_name}}' already exists."
    }
    else
    {
      .\rabbitmqctl.bat add_user {{ansible_play_name}} "{{rabbitmq_password}}"
      .\rabbitmqctl.bat set_permissions {{ansible_play_name}} ".*" ".*" ".*"
      .\rabbitmqctl.bat set_user_tags {{ansible_play_name}} administrator
    }
  register: rabbit_add_user_out
  changed_when: '"Adding user" in rabbit_add_user_out.stdout'
  failed_when: '"Error" in rabbit_add_user_out.stderr'
```

Anyone have any suggestions as to why it wouldn't be able to pick up this value? The playbook it is running from has fact gathering set to true as well so it should be assigned

Comment: can you please show line 32, column 3, because the error is in another task i suppose as it shows name: Text\n  ^ here

Comment: @smiles Apologies, I have made it clearer in the question where it is pointed, line 32 is the top line of the ansible task provided

Comment: one more question, is ansible_play_name used anywhere else in the playbook, also is the other facts working? please test using debug: msg: "{{ansible_play_name}"" to see if it works

Comment: what is the version of your ansible, this is Added in 2.8.

Comment: It is used in other places but I had made an assumption that I had the most recent version of ansible when I just ran apt-get and apt-get upgrade to install it this week but apparently debian doesn't contain 2.8 normally and 2.7.7 was installed. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ansible_play_name - (The name of the currently executed play) is Added in 2.8. May be you have a lower version.